# Two-way data binding through property-changed does not work for dom-bind

Tags: javascript, data-binding, polymer

I'm trying to make Polymer's two-way data binding work with my native custom elements within auto-binding `dom-bind`.
I follow [the docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#change-notification-protocol) which says:

> When using a Polymer element with other elements or frameworks, you can manually attach an on-property-changed listener to an element to be notified of property changes, and take the necessary actions based on the new value.

So I created an element, and attached binding to it:

```
<my-element notify="{{text}}"></my-element>
```

Then, to follow notification protocol, I attached listeners to `property-changed` event, I have tried attaching them via `addEventListener`, `on-property-changed` attribute, none of those worked.

Property gets changed, but I get no notification, and cannot use it.

Live example: http://jsbin.com/dijequ/edit?html,output

I'm using it within `dom-bind` element, and I cannot use `$=` as I need direct property binding, as in my real case I need to bind to a shared data object.

Is it a bug in Polymer, a bug in docs, or am I doing something wrong? How can I get notified about property changes?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I have found is to define just plain JS setter.

So by disregarding Polymer's protocol, we can get framework agnostic functionality:

```
MyElementPrototype.createdCallback = function(event){
  var notify= null;
  Object.defineProperty(this, "notify",{
    set: function(newValue){
      notify = newValue;
      console.log('setter was notified');
    },
    get: function(){
      return notify;
    }
  });
};
```

Working example: http://jsbin.com/bezuya/edit?html,output